# PHP: Most Efficient way in initializing large amount of multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the most efficient way in initializing large amount of multidimensional array in PHP?

example: I'm going to create 100 Multidimensional array that look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 5
        )
      .......
)
```

Currently, I'm using this code to create the array shown above:

```
// 100 arrays
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
   $array[$i]['multi']=$i;
}
```

I also found an alternative way by using `array_fill()` and `array_fill_keys()`, but It only allows the same value to be initialized in an array:

```
$array = array_fill(1, 100, array_fill_keys(array("multi"), "value_here"));
```

QUESTION: Is there a more efficient way in initializing this kind of array in terms of speed?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the point of the "multi" key. if the data you want to store is just sequentially ascending integers, why do you need this structure? Seems like `range(1, 100)` should do the job just fine. Can you post a less contrived example? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: use a generator

Comment: sorry.The structure of my array has one or more different keys inside them, except for the key "multi". They all have the key "multi". I only include the code for initializing the "multi" key.

Comment: If it's static then save it as a json and you won't have to initialize it each time

Comment: The fastest way to initialize an Array Is by the standard Array initializer: `$array = [...];`

Comment: @andreas thats gonna be slower then other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_map` over the range of values you want:

```
$array = array_map(function ($v) { return array('multi' => $v); }, range(0, 5));
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 3
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 4
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 5
        )
)
```

If you don't want the `0` element, just `unset($array[0]);`

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kJlvr)